# will puting function inside render method slow my app

Tags: reactjs, fetch-api

i am learning react, i am django developer and i am getting data from api and is working fine, just for a fun i wanted to update data without clicking reload, so what i did is put fetch function inside render which is looping , and it is giving real time feel, but i want to know that will doing this like this slow my app like in vannila js, since it is rendering again and again, but since react uses virtual dom i have soft side on this technique

```
    import React from 'react';


class FetchRandomUser extends React.Component {

    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            data: [],
        };
    }

    fetchdata(){
        fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api')
        .then(response=>response.json())
        .then((data)=>{
            this.setState({
                data:data,
            });
            console.log(data);
        });
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this.fetchdata();
    }

    
    
    
    render() {
        this.fetchdata();
        const dat = this.state.data;
        const rows = dat.map((emp)=>
        <div>
            <h1>{emp.id}</h1>
            <h1>{emp.title}</h1>
            <h1>{emp.body}</h1>
        </div>
        );
        return (
            <div>
               {rows} 
            </div>
        )
       }
    }

    export default FetchRandomUser;
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `fetch` inside render method. Because in your code when `this.fetchData()` is run, as you can see you are setting the `state` in that method using `setState()`, and `setState` itself calls `render` method so your code will result in an infinite loop.
Also You shouldn't use fetch inside render method because every time render is called your `fetchData()` will run which will slow your program as it takes time to fetch data from a server.

Comment: So what's solution?

Comment: The best way to use fetch in react is to call inside a lifecycle method `componentDidMount()`. This method runs immediately after render method is called for the very first time.